# Conducting t-tests within the same column of data?

Tags: r

Using a .txt file, I'm attempting to conduct an unpaired t-test between columns `FBC` and `MBC`, and between `FFS` and `MFS`. However, I have far more data in the `MBC` and `MFS` columns. A quick example of my problem:

```
FBC FFS MBC MFS
5   4   5   5
4   4   5   1
5   3   2   3
5   2   4   2
3   4   3   3
        4   3
        3   3
        5   4
        5   3
        5   4
```

Now, I can't run the test like this because there are not the same amount of elements in those last few lines, so R won't recognize the table. So what I'm attempting is to rearrange the table like so:

```
FBC FFS
5   4
4   4
5   3
5   2
3   4
MBC MFS
5   5
5   1
2   3
4   2
3   3
4   3
3   3
5   4
5   3
5   4
```

So that every line has an equal amount of elements. Problem is, I have no idea how to run a t-test between groups in the same column, if it can even be done. I've been unable to find an answer to my problem, and was wondering if anyone had any code that would allow me to do so. Or if I'm on a wild goose chase, that'd be helpful to know too.

My apologies if there have been similar questions asked, but I've been unable to find them; I'm also a bit of a novice to R.

Comment: I think you incorrectly assume that to use `t.test`, you must put everything in the same `data.frame`. This is not true. Just store `FBC` and `FFS` in one `data.frame` (df1), and `MBC` and `MFS` in another `data.frame` (df2). Then run `t.test(df1$FBC,df2$MBC)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem.  Consider:

```
dframe <- read.table(text="FBC FFS MBC MFS
5   4   5   5
4   4   5   1
5   3   2   3
5   2   4   2
3   4   3   3
NA  NA  4   3
NA  NA  3   3
NA  NA  5   4
NA  NA  5   3
NA  NA  5   4", header=T)

with(dframe, t.test(FBC, MBC))

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  FBC and MBC
t = 0.5658, df = 9.841, p-value = 0.5842
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8839444  1.4839444
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      4.4       4.1 

with(dframe, t.test(FFS, MFS))

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  FFS and MFS
t = 0.5658, df = 9.841, p-value = 0.5842
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8839444  1.4839444
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      3.4       3.1
```